# Dynamically populate dropdown list from database based on selection in other dropdown lists using dojo

Tags: database, servlets, drop-down-menu, dojo, cascadingdropdown

I just want to know how to design the UI with Dojo
I want to populate the dropdowns based on other dropdown selections,and the relationship can be one-to-many, i.e the 2nd dropdown will be populated based on the first one, but then, the 3rd dropdown would be poupulated based on the 1st and the 2nd one and so on.
my requirement is that whenever i select an option in a dropdown, it should be sent to a servlet(running on a given URL) with the selected choice (and any selections made previous to that), so that the servlet could return the data with which to populate the next dropdown

specific Questions

1. how do i write the code for dropdown form elements (using dojo)
2. how do i send the data back from the servlet to the webpage so that it will be read by dojo populated in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets